# $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and finding non-zero $y,z$ such that $yz =0$

Tags: ring-theory

> Find  $\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z$ $ab=0.$

I really am lost on how to start the question. Can anyone throw me a bone?

Comment: Suppose that the prime factorization of $455$ is $(p_1)^{a_1} \times \cdots \times (p_r)^{a_r}.$  **If** I am interpreting the question correctly, for each prime $p_i$ in $\{p_1, \cdots, p_r\}$, then $p_i$ must show in one or both of the prime factorizations of $x,y$ such that the prime factorization of $(x \times y)$ contains $(p_i)^{b_i} ~: ~b_i \geq a_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: In $\mathbb Z_{12}$, solutions would be $(3,4),(2,6),(6,6),(8,9)$ among others. Do you see how to find solutions? It's all about factorisaion.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque My mistake, thank you for pointing it out. I can't delete it now unfortunately.